# Is it appropriate to use participles for passive voice in Esperanto?

Tags: verbs, participles

> AS mainly shows the present tense of the action, while ANT and AT show the **duration or repetition** of the action. IS shows that the action occured before the present, while INT and IT show that the actions **was completed possibly before another action**...

This is what I got about usages of participles on [lernu.net](https://lernu.net/en/gramatiko/participoj). I got to know that the participles and indicative verbs have differences. However, when we implement passive voices, the differences seem to be blurred.

> Ŝi **skribas** la leteron.
> *"writing" happens at present, or as a habitual action.*

> La letero **estas skribata**.
> *According to the definition on lernu.net, "writing" as a participle, indicates duration or repetition.*

So what if I just want to simply express a present action in the passive sentence, not to emphasize that it’s happening now or it’s repetitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a letter isn't an instantaneous action. It does take some time, so implying duration shouldn't distort the meaning. Thus

> La letero estas skribata (de ŝi).

is the correct passive form for the usual meaning(s) of "Ŝi skribas la leteron.".

See also section [Passive — choosing a participle](https://lernu.net/en/gramatiko/participoj#pasivo-participojelekto) in the lernu grammar chapter you referred to, as well as the corresponding chapter in PMEG [29.2. Pasivo – participelekto](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/pasivo/participelekto/).

If it's a habitual action, you can add "ree kaj ree" (again and again) without distorting the meaning:

> La letero estas ree kaj ree skribata (de ŝi).

(Implying that she writes the (same?) letter several times, over and over.)

If you can add "plu kaj plu" (more and more / continuously) **or** "iom post iom" (bit by bit) without distorting the meaning (usually the case for continuous actions), *·at·* can also be used. In your example, "iom post iom" *does* seem a bit akward, but doesn't significantly change the meaning:

> La letero estas iom post iom skribata (de ŝi).

As the two grammar resources state, the possibility to form these "control sentences" indicates that *skrib**at**a* is the correct participle here.

Comment: En `la letero estas ree kaj ree skribata de ŝi` mi komprenas ke ŝi ne sukcesas fini ĝin. Mi povas imagi ŝin serĉante la ĝustajn vortojn dum pilkoj paperaj amasiĝas surplanke, ĉiu farita de maltrafita malneto...

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn’t “ree kaj ree” be too strange? Because (according to my knowledge) there’re not many languages using  such expressions in sentences as simple as writing a letter. Is it special to Esperanto?

Answer (score 2):

The passive voice can be expressed in two ways.

**Personless passive**

The so called *oni-pasivo* puts the focus on action, what happens to the object. Cf. man-passive found in many Germanic languages (but not for instance in English).

- *Ŝi **skribas** la leteron → Oni **skribas** la leteron / La leteron oni **skribas**.*

Here the information who performs the action is lost, but the focus is clearly on the action. This passive is easy to form: just replace the person pronoun with *oni*. Because of that easiness this is usually the most recommended way to express the passive voice.

**Describing passive**

The compound passive or *esti-pasivo* describes the change of state caused by the action.

- *Ŝi **skriba̲s** la leteron → La letero estas **skriba̲ta** de ŝi.*

As Eduardo stated use the same tense in the passive participle as you have in the corresponding active voice verb.

This passive has several points worth noticing:

- the focus is no longer in the action but in a description of the change of the state (this may sound a minor thing but in some contexts it may matter)
- what is conceptually an object (like the letter in your example), is now suddenly a subject (since you just describe the change); this may confuse people with some language backgrounds
- you can form this form only from transitive verbs, i.e. you cannot say **estas kurata** (in comparison *oni kuras* is fine)
- in this kind of passive sentence *de* **always** marks the agent which causes problems should you need to use *de* for some other purpose (and *de* is the most overloaded preposition in Esperanto, see [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#de_kd))

Answer (score 1):

> So what if I just want to simply express a present action in the passive sentence, just like the active one?

Short answer: You would then stick to the `a/i/o` ending in the active form:

```
mi farbas la domon -> la domo estas farbata
```

The action is in progress.

```
mi farbis la domon -> la domo estas farbita
```

The action is completed.

```
mi farbos la domon -> la domo estas farbota
```

The action will start in the future.

Note that, if you don't want to lose information, you have to add the active agent, in these cases: `de mi`.